# My Wordpress home page runs very slow only on Chrome

Tags: jquery, wordpress, performance, google-chrome, slider

I have noticed that my Wordpress site's homepage runs extremely slow only on Chrome. The hover on the menus takes a few seconds to show. The site runs smoothly if I disable the slider, but I need the slider.

Everything runs smoothly on Firefox and IE9.

Anybody know what the issue may be?

The site is [here](http://www.houserepairscy.com)

Comment: `GET http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.1.2/jquery.tools.min.js?ver=1.3.2 404 (Not Found) ` Update wordpress maybe?

Comment: Try http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js

Comment: And you have a [broken link](http://houserepairscy.com/wp-content/themes/bootstrap-ecommerce/img/glyphicons-halflings.png "Broken!"), that's where it chokes and produces a 1.5 second delay in chrome...

Comment: Tried those, none of these work. Any other ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions asking for a specific external link to be looked at are too localised, and are of no use once the problem has been fixed.